# Models has change in Django but they are not reflected in celery

Tags: database, docker, celery, django-celery

I have a Django project running inside a Docker container. Celery Worker, Celery Beat, Redis and Postgres are running inside it containers too.

My problem is that i made some changes in a Django model then generate migration, applied it and everything works.

When celery tries to save an instance of that model, i get the classic Django error: The col  non exists.

My question is: Do i have to do something like apply migrations in celery?

Thanks for your help,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your celery workers as well to load the latest code.